# Emacs Evil mouse clicks don't work in motion state

Tags: emacs, mouseevent

I'm using Emacs Evil. Whenever I'm in motion state, mouse clicks don't work. For example, if I go to recent files (`recentf`), and wanna click some file, I am forced to switch to Emacs state for it to work. How can I make them work in motion mode as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only motion state binding that affects "mouse-1" is that defined in [evil-maps.el](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/blob/master/evil-maps.el#L421).

Therefore, you can try to un-define it, so that any other mapping of mouse 1 button (made by other modes) would work instead (by "poking a hole" in evil motion's keymap):

```
(eval-after-load "evil-maps"
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map [down-mouse-1] nil))
```

If you're loading evil with `use-package`, you can write only the `define-key` line somewhere in evil's `:config` section).

```
(use-package evil
  :ensure t
  :init
  ...
  :config
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map [down-mouse-1] nil)
  ...)
```